# How do I skip header files when reading from google cloud storage in a dataflow job?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I'm working on a data processing pipeline where we read a lot of files from cloud storage. The files might be csv files with a header row, which I need to remove so I don't get errors down the line.

If possible I would love to use:

```
TextIO.Read.from(filePattern)
```

together with something else since it automatically handles compression and such. Ideally it should look something like this:

```
TextIO.Read.from(filePattern, numberOfHeaderRows)
```

and that should just exclude `numberOfHeaderRows` from the top. What is the easiest way to achieve something like this in java?

Answer (score -1):

The easiest path is likely to use `TextIO.Read.from(filePattern)` followed by a `ParDo` that filters out the header rows.

Comment: That won't work since you can't know which lines are header lines. The format of the header will differ from time to time, and also the number of lines.

Comment: Since text files may be read in pieces by multiple machines, it isn't easy to identify which lines came from the start of the file. Ideally, the file header would be clearly distinguishable from the actual content rows, and could be filtered out as described.